# Get type of Object from constructor for generic parameters?

Tags: java, object, generics, collections, linked-list

```
private LinkedList register;

public Register(Object obj){
    register = new LinkedList<obj>();
}
```

So basically, can I define the type of objects that the LinkedList should contain through this method? (For Java)

Perhaps obj.getClass?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The language is Java.

Comment: Have you considered using generics?

Comment: How would I write that? I've tried, but I don't seem to program it correct.
new LinkedList<E>() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially no, generics are compile time only and need to be declared somewhere.

```
class Register<T> {
    LinkedList<T> register;

    Register(T obj) {
        register = new LinkedList<T>();
    }
```

You could, for example, use a factory method.

```
    static <U> Register<U> of(U obj) {
        Register<U> result = new Register<U>(obj);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
Register<String> a = new Register<String>("abc");
Register<Double> b = Register.of(1.0d);
```

See also [*Lesson: Generics*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: Thanks, but why don't you use obj in the constructor instead of "T" (new LinkedList<obj>) ? But I'll check out the lesson, thanks again!

Comment: @Duy `obj` is a variable, not a type. We use `T` because `T` is the type of `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Generics can be confusing. I think you want this:

```
public class Register<T> {
    private LinkedList<T> register = new LinkedList<T>();

    public static <T> Register<T> create(T object) {
        return new Register<T>();
    }
}
```